# Using Apache VFS Library Get File Size (Symbolic Link)

Tags: apache-commons-vfs

I utilize the Apache VFS library to access files on a remote server.  Some files are symbolic links and when we get the file size of these files, it comes back as 80 bytes.  I need to get the actual file size.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Using commons-vfs2 version 2.1.

OS is Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which protocol/provider you are using. However it most likely also does not matter: none of them implement symlink chasing as far as I know (besides local). You only get the size reported by the server for the actual directory entry.

VFS is a rather high level abstraction, if you want to commandeer a protocol client more specially, using *commons-net* or *httpclient* or whatever protocol you want to use gives you much more options.